# Pull to refresh UITableView without UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to implement a pull to refresh feature in a UITableView within a UIViewController. I can't use a UITableViewController because I want the UITableView to be a smaller subview in the view controller, with some other stuff above it. I assume this is possible, but has anyone seen an implementation of it?

Answer (score 470, accepted):

Add a refresh control directly to a `UITableView` without using a `UITableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl
    }
}

@objc func refresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    // Do your job, when done:
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe UIRefreshControl is new. I think this is now the best way to do this.

Comment: So, basically the refreshControl becomes the header of UITableView?

Comment: Excellent and easy. It works for me when I tried it on a table view added to UIViewController on iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: has anyone had the problem where the control itself is not visible but otherwise seems to work fine?

Comment: Does not work properly if you have a positive top contentInset.

Comment: Table view seems to jump down unexpectedly once it "clicks". Not sure why yet.

Comment: I found that it needs to go in viewdidappear, not sure if that is an iOS 7 feature - I am yet to test it in iOS 8...

Comment: @BobSpryn every figure out why it jumps down when it "clicks". Very annoying and making me consider just using a UITableViewController.

Comment: The refreshControl appears on top of the tableView. I fixed this by: `tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 0)` instead of `tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)`

Comment: the refresh control is not centered

Comment: If the initial swipe makes refreshControl jump over the tableView, use clear background color refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; You still will see the tableViews background, since the refreshControl is not above it but init.

Comment: Be careful with this method if you have tableview headers. The headers will float below the refresh control, yet the tableview content will scroll above refresh control giving an odd effect. This does not occur when setting a UIRefreshControl on a UITableViewController

Comment: New way of using selector in Swift : #selector(YourClass.refresh)

Answer (score 13):

***Objective-C***:

This is how you can implement pull to refresh for table view.
Same as in the case of collection view. Just replace table view alloc with collection view.

```
UITableView *tableViewDemo  =  [[UITableView alloc]init];
tableViewDemo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
tableViewDemo.dataSource =  self;
tableViewDemo.delegate =  self;
[self.view addSubView: tableViewDemo];

UIRefreshControl *refreshController = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshController addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[tableViewDemo addSubview:refreshController];

#pragma mark - Handle Refresh Method

-(void)handleRefresh : (id)sender
{
   NSLog (@"Pull To Refresh Method Called");
   [refreshController endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: How does the obj-c version only have 9 upvotes when the swift version has >430?

Comment: @ChaseRoberts, That one is answered on Feb 13, have a look at the edit history, originally it was in objective-c, Since at that time swift was new, every one was looking for swift version...  
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15010646/revisions

Answer (score 4):

This solution from @berik works fine but the UIController is displayed on top of the UITableViewController. The way to fix it is doing this change:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl // <- THIS!!!
}

func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    // Do your job, when done:
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: The refreshControl appears on top of the tableView for me, but your suggestion makes my `refreshControl` disappear, not appear below the `tableView`. I fixed this by: tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 0) instead of tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented EGORefreshTableHeaderView with a UIViewController and a simple table view, the trick is that a in the places where EGO takes a scroll view as a parameter, if you look the table view itself inherits from scroll view.

It only requires that and a few extra connections :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that if you create the UIRefreshControl inside the viewController's **loadView** method everything works fine. The UIRefreshControl behaves as it should. Tested with iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.2

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl).
It doesn't need any hack like the above `tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl`, works almost the same way, and gives a better looking UI.