# UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

Just curious, as it doesn't immediately seem possible, but is there a sneaky way to leverage the new iOS 6 `UIRefreshControl` class without using a `UITableViewController` subclass?

I often use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` subview and conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` rather than using a `UITableViewController` outright.

Comment: @DaveDeLong : No, Dave, what should he do? Later on this page you say his solution isn't supported, so what's the right solution?

Comment: @matt he should use a `UITableViewController` and file a bug requesting API to use a `UIRefreshControl` with a `UITableView` directly.

Comment: UITableViewController has had (and continues to have) too many obscure and niche bugs and problems with non-trivial view hierarchies ... that all magically disappear when you switch to using a standard VC with a TableView subview. "Use UITVC" is a poor start to any solution, IMHO.

Comment: @Adam Do these bugs surface when using the 'UITableViewController' as a child view controller (thus giving access to view customization without mucking around in the tableViewControllers hierarchy)? I've never encountered issues when using it this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull to refresh UITableView without UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291537/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-without-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 388, accepted):

On a hunch, and based on DrummerB's inspiration, I tried simply adding a `UIRefreshControl` instance as a subview to my `UITableView`. And it magically just works!

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

This adds a `UIRefreshControl` above your table view and works as expected without having to use a `UITableViewController` :)

---

EDIT: This above still works but as a few have pointed out, there is a slight "stutter" when adding the UIRefreshControl in this manner. A solution to that is to instantiate a UITableViewController, and then setting your UIRefreshControl and UITableView to that, i.e.:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(getConnections) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

Comment: FYI, this is unsupported behavior and may change in the future.  The only guarantee that Apple makes is that using it according to the provided api (in this case `-[UITableViewController setRefreshControl:]`) will continue to function.

Comment: With this implementation, it seems that right before triggering `handleRefresh:` there's an unexpected change in value of the scroll view's `contentInsets` for a split second.  Anyone else experience this or have a fix for it? (yup, I know this is unsupported in the first place!)

Comment: You really should simply use a Container View for this. Just set its view controller's class to your custom subclass of `UITableViewController` and you'll be "doing it right".

Comment: Added an answer which doesn't have the stutter problem.

Comment: In iOS7 (unknown for iOS6) the edited version works fine except for when you close and reopen the app. The animation doesn't play until the 2nd time you refresh. The first time refreshing after reopening the app, its just a full circle instead of the incrementing circle based on how far you pull it down. Is there a fix?

Comment: It's been a while since this answer was posted and accepted. How has this solution been working for everyone so far?

Comment: I still get a slight 'stutter' in my tableview using the 'edit' solution in this answer. It's not as bad as when using addSubView but it is still quite noticeable.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13077326/1219956) is a much more elegant solution, and you can still use the interface builder and you arent doing anything dodgy in terms of unsupported behaviour

Comment: To avoid having the "slutter" as mentioned above while still bypassing the UITableViewController, just add the refresh control beneath the table view like so: `[_tableView insertSubview:_refreshControl atIndex:0];`. Tested with both iOS 7 and 8 ;)

Comment: @ptitvinou can you elaborate more? I may be stupid with these controls but I can't get it to work without the 'jump' or 'slutter', it just doesn't look good anyhow

Comment: @ptitvinou thanks for the quick reply! Apparently my issue is a different one than this "slutter". When I add the `UIRefreshControl` to the uitableview, it 'jumps' when it hits the 'refresh' offset. When I add it to UITableViewController it jumps too. Did you meet this issue too? I couldn't find any working solution for me (for iOS 7,8) in any of the uirefreshcontrol x uitableview threads...

Comment: As for the jump issue I do have a little one when a reach the refresh offset. I must admit I don't know why and not really a concern to me but If you already tried with a UITableViewController (which I didn't) and this happens too then I'd say that this is the component limitation. Don't hesitate to share a solution if you find one :)

Comment: I ended up using a third-party class `SVPullToRefresh` (https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) which had it's issues too (= with trying to hide search bar on `UITableView` with contentSize lower than tableView height....) but with no text the arrow itself makes a nice effect, and at least it doesn't have 'unsolvable internal' problems like the default `UIRefreshControl` :)

Comment: I've solved problem with "stutter" by removing `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`

Comment: The basic version works for me except that the refresh control is aligned right of center. No idea how to fix that either.

Comment: @alper are you sure your table view has appropriate auto layout constraints  connected to your view (leading and trailing in particular)?

Comment: Ah, that was indeed it. My entire table view was stretching right off screen and it took me some time to figure that out (the UI inspector doesn't really show that).

Comment: Just had a little problem and this might be helpful. Don't forget setting `tableView`'s `bounces` property to `YES` ;)

Answer (score 94):

To eliminate the stutter that is caused by the accepted answer, you can assign your `UITableView` to a `UITableViewController`.

```
_tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self addChildViewController:_tableViewController];

_tableViewController.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[_tableViewController.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadStream) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

_theTableView = _tableViewController.tableView;
```

**EDIT:**

A way to add a `UIRefreshControl` with no `UITableViewController` with no stutter and retain the nice animation after refreshing data on the tableview.

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.theTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
[self.theTableView sendSubviewToBack:refreshControl];
```

Later when handling the refreshed data...

```
- (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [self.theTableView reloadData];
    [self.theTableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: You don't even have to create a new UITableView. Just say initWithStyle:existingTableView.style - and then afterwards do newTableViewController.tableView = existingTableView and assign refreshControl. Boils this down to three lines.

Comment: Don't forget to call `[_tablewViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];` after adding the subview.

Comment: `self.tableView = _tableViewController.tableView;` should be `_tableViewController.tableView = self.tableView`

Comment: @Linus why is that neccessary? I added _tableViewController.view as a subView in my custom viewController's viewDidLoad method and that seemed to do the trick. I didn't even need to set _tableViewController.tableView

Comment: The reason that I cannot user a UITableViewController and am using a UIViewController w/ a table view inside. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar

Comment: @lostintranslation you can absolutely use what I have here within a `UIViewController` the example above is actually inside a UIViewController ViewDidLoad function.

Comment: This solution is nearly there - however for me, at the point where the refresh is triggered, the tableView jumps about 40 pixels down the screen.

Comment: Still seeing the stutter with iOS 9 ... anyone else have it working ?

Answer (score 21):

What you would try is use container view inside ViewController you are using. you can define clean UITableViewController subclass with dedicated tableview and place that in the ViewController.

Comment: Precisely, the cleanest way seems to be adding child view controller of UITableViewController type.

Comment: You can then grab the UITableViewController using `self.childViewControllers.firstObject`.

Comment: ^ you might also want to consider using `prepareForSegue` to get a reference to the UITableViewController object in a container view as this is immediately triggered as a segue event on instantiation from the storyboard.

Answer (score 18):

Well UIRefreshControl is a UIView subclass, so you can use it on it's own. I'm not sure though how it renders itself. The rendering could simply depend on the frame, but it also could rely on a UIScrollView or the UITableViewController.

Either way, it's going to be more of a hack than an elegant solution. I recommend you look into one of the available 3rd party clones or write your own.

[**ODRefreshControl**](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl)

[image]

[**SlimeRefresh**](https://github.com/dbsGen/SlimeRefresh)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not exactly what I was looking for. The first sentence of your post did, however, inspire me to try what ended up being the solution though!

Comment: ODRefreshControl is awesome - thanks for the tip! Very simple, and does the job. And of course much more flexible than Apple's. I never understood why anyone would use UITableViewController, IMO the worst class in the whole API. It does (next to) nothing, but makes your views inflexible.

Comment: It actually depends on your project what you use in there .. using a uitableview in my case was increasing complexity of the project and now i switched to uitableviewcontroller which sort of divided my code into two segments i am happy i have 2 smaller files that can be used to debug instead of one huge file ..

Comment: @n13 Hello, a good reason to use UITableViewController is being able to design with static cells. Unfortunately unavailable in a tableView residing in a UIViewController.

Comment: @JeanLeMoignanThe iOS tools and libraries are changing quickly so a 3 year old comment of mine is no longer valid. I've switched to creating all user interfaces in code with SnapKit and honestly it's hugely more efficient than clicking 10 thousand times in interface builder. Also changing a UITableViewController to a UIViewController is easy and only takes a second, whereas in IB it's a big pain.

Comment: Oh and refreshcontrol is no longer an issue... no need for 3rd party libraries anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Try delaying the call to the refreshControl `-endRefresh` method by a fraction of a second after the tableView reloads its contents, either by using NSObject's `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or GCD's `dispatch_after`.

I created a category on UIRefreshControl for this:

```
@implementation UIRefreshControl (Delay)

- (void)endRefreshingAfterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self endRefreshing];
    });
}

@end
```

I tested it and this also works on Collection Views. I've noticed that a delay as small as
0.01 seconds is enough:

```
// My data refresh process here while the refresh control 'isRefreshing'
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.refreshControl endRefreshingAfterDelay:.01];
```

Comment: Delays and waits are really bad style.

Comment: @orkoden I agree. This is a workaround for an already unsupported use of `UIRefreshControl`.

Comment: You can call a method with a delay a lot easier with. `[self performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01]`

Comment: The end effect is exactly the same, and doesn’t makes the ‘hack’ more/less elegant. Whether to use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or GCD for this is up to a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 7):

> **IOS 10 Swift 3.0**

*it's simple*

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
            let title = NSLocalizedString("PullToRefresh", comment: "Pull to refresh")
            refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title)
            refreshControl.addTarget(self,
                                     action: #selector(refreshOptions(sender:)),
                                     for: .valueChanged)
            myTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        }
    }

    @objc private func refreshOptions(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        // Perform actions to refresh the content
        // ...
        // and then dismiss the control
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(String(indexPath.row))"
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

*If you want to learn about iOS 10 UIRefreshControl read [**here**](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/refresh-control-changes-in-ios-10/).*

Answer (score 3):

Adding the refresh control as a subview creates an empty space above section headers.

Instead, I embedded a UITableViewController into my UIViewController, then changed my `tableView` property to point towards the embedded one, and viola!  Minimal code changes. :-)

Steps:

1. Create a new UITableViewController in Storyboard and embed it into your original UIViewController
2. Replace `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` with the one from the newly embedded UITableViewController, as shown below

---

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tableViewController = self.childViewControllers.first as! UITableViewController
        tableView = tableViewController.tableView
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // Now we can (properly) add the refresh control
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 2.2 .**

First make UIRefreshControl() .

```
var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl!
```

In your viewDidLoad() method add:

```
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing..")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourUIViewController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

And make refresh function

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    // do something ...

    // reload tableView
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // End refreshing
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which is a little different.

I had to use it because of some view hierarchy issues I had: I was creating some functionality that required passing views around to different places in the view hierarchy, which broken when using a UITableViewController's tableview b/c the tableView is the UITableViewController's root view (self.view) and not just a regular view, it created inconsistent controller / view hierarchies and caused a crash.

Basically create your own subclass of UITableViewController and override loadView to assign self.view a different view, and override  the tableView property to return a separate tableview.

for example:

```
@interface MyTableVC : UITableViewController
@end

@interface MyTableVC ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *separateTableView;
@end

@implementation MyTableVC

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.separateTableView;
}

- (void)setTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    self.separateTableView = tableView;
}

@end
```

When combined with Keller's solution this will more robust in the sense that the tableView is now a regular view, not a VC's root view, and be more robust against changing view hierarchies. Example of using it this way:

```
MyTableVC *tableViewController = [[MyTableVC alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(getConnections) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

There is another possible use for this:

Since subclassing this way separates self.view from self.tableView, it's possible now to use this UITableViewController as more of a regular controller, and add other subviews to self.view without the oddities of adding subviews to UITableView, so one may considering making their view controllers directly a subclass of UITableViewController instead of having UITableViewController children.

Some things to watch out for:

Since we're overriding the tableView property without calling super, there may be some things to watch out for and should handle where necessary.  For example, setting the tableview in my above example will not add the tableview to self.view and not set the frame which you may want to do.  Also, in this implementation there is no default tableView given to you when the class is instantiated, which is also something you may consider adding.  I don't include it here because that is case by case, and this solution actually fits well with Keller's solution.

Comment: The question specified "without using a UITableViewController subclass", and this answer is for a UITableViewController subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

The Above solutions are fine but tableView.refreshControl is available for UITableViewController only, till iOS 9.x and comes in UITableView from iOS 10.x onwards.

Written in Swift 3 -

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedViewController.loadNewData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
// Fix for the RefreshControl Not appearing in background
tableView?.addSubview(refreshControl)
tableView.sendSubview(toBack: refreshControl)
```

Comment: Best solution so far

Answer (score -1):

Keller's first suggestion causes a strange bug in iOS 7 where the inset of the table is increased after the view controller reappears. Changing to the second answer, using the uitableviewcontroller, fixed things for me.

Answer (score -6):

It turns out you can use the following when you use a UIViewController with a UITableView subview and conform to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Disagree.  `self.refreshControl` is a property for a `UITableViewController`, not a `UIViewController`.

Comment: NOT WORKING, refershControl is not defined for uiviewcontroller