# Is there a horizontal UIRefreshControl?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios6, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

You can add `UIRefreshControl` to `UICollectionView` (or any `UIScrollView` for that matter) by [adding it to collection's subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502450/458193):

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

This doesn't work when collection view layout has [`UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal).

I tried overriding `layoutSubviews` to put refresh control to the left, but it wouldn't track scrolling progress this way. Can I trick it into working with horizontal layouts?

Comment: Maybe I'm being conservative but although you can add this view in that way, and get it to work, I don't think it was designed for that, the documentation does clearly link it to UITableView.

Comment: @Daniel While this is true, I'm seeing a lot of people here doing it this way which makes me feel Apple is likely to make this de facto working behavior official. I also haven't seen a single post saying their app was rejected for using `UIRefreshControl` without a table view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find any existing solutions so I extended [`ODRefreshControl`](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) with horizontal layout support:

[image]

I needed solution in MonoTouch (C#) so I started by source-porting ODRefreshControl and then [patched it to work](https://github.com/stampsy/MonoTouch.ODRefreshControl/blob/master/ODRefreshControl.cs) with horizontal layout.

Full C# source code is [here](https://github.com/stampsy/MonoTouch.ODRefreshControl/blob/master/ODRefreshControl.cs), it should be straightforward to port it back to Objective C.
All I did was add an utility function and some conditions here and there.

Comment: Hi, could you offer your extension code with objective-c? Thank you!

Comment: @Dan Please provide the code  you made in Obj-C PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE

Answer (score 1):

you  can achieve this by implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
     CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
     UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
     float y = offset.x + bounds.size.width - inset.right;
     float h = size.width;


    float reload_distance = 75; //distance for which you want to load more
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
       // write your code getting the more data
       NSLog(@"load more rows");

    }
}
```