# UIViewController as Apple PodCast application

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I want to make an application with an UI looks like [apple podcast application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/581jkap5c0czyz2/photo%20%281%29.PNG).

There are 2 parts on this `UIViewController`:

1. fixed part with buttons and Image
2. `tableview` with `refreshcontrol`

This is this last point my problem: `refreshcontrol`. I found a previous [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller), but adding  `refreshcontrol` directly on my view breaks all cells and table styles.

Do you know how can I make a view with these traits: `fixed part`, `refreshcontrol` and `tableview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIViewController` containment.

You can have a parent view controller that includes the a view for the fixed part at the top, and a `UITableView` at the bottom.

For the `UITableView` you can contain a `UITableViewController` as a child view controller, so you can use the `UIRefreshControl` as intended.

Comment: Great! It's the solution, thanks!