# refresh controller for embedded tableview ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

Hi i currently have embedded tableview in UIViewController. In the tableview i have collection of json data. I wish to make a refresh controller, so whenever the user pulls down, the json data is refreshed.

I have tried the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[superviewDidLoad];

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]
init];
[refreshControl addTarget:nil action:@selector(updateArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

}

-(void) updateArray{
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

I am getting an error which says property refreshControl not found in ViewController.

Is it because i am using embedded tableview or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this code in your `UIViewController` or elsewhere?

Comment: the code is in UIViewController

Comment: It looks like the refresh control handling needs to be in a UITableViewController, not a UIViewController.  See, perhaps, [this tutorial](http://www.lextech.com/2012/10/ios-6-pull-to-refresh-tutorial/).

Comment: I have seen that tutorial thats when i understood you need UITableViewController, therefore i was wondering if there was a way around that? As i need to refresh my tableview which is in UIViewController.

Comment: I've used [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) to make pull-to-refresh happen in iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks for that i will have a look into that and update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the UIRefreshControl inside the viewDidLoad method. The reference to that object is not visible to the updateArray method. You will need to either make it a property or a instance variable.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

then instead of

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

use

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

Comment: If you are still having the issue, you would have to to post more details of your code. Maybe try change in your addTarget: method to self instead of nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIRefreshControl only to UITableViewController and not UIViewController. 
Check this answer for using UIRefreshControl in UIViewController where UITableViewController is child.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148118/1017099