# Using refreshControl from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I currently have a `UIViewController` that has two `UIViews`, hiding and un-hiding them via `segmentedControl`. I want to be able to implement the `pull-to-refresh` feature, which is easy if I had a `UITableViewController`. But I don't have that right now, so am pretty lost as to what to do.

This obviously will give me errors because `UIViewController` doesn't have a `refreshControl`

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't really find any solutions on my own, but yeah that answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

UIRefreshControl can only used in UITableViewController Class.

Comment: Yeah, but he is asking for options to implement that functionality, right?