# How to end UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have created a UIRefreshcontrol without a TableViewController. My question is how I would end it inside another method?
This is how I created it;

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered with help from @Justin Paulsson that this could be done;

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

-

```
-(void) handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)controller
    {
        //Refresh code
        controller.endRefreshing;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documented way is using an `UITableViewController`. Anything else can work, but as it's not documented, it may break on next iOS versions.

I'd just use an `UITableViewController` in your case.

Comment: Yes I understand that would be a preferred way, but how would I do that?
I'd prefer to keep it this way, and end it somehow still.

Comment: To keep using the way you're trying, you need to store a reference of `refreshControl` in a property or ivar, so you can use it later to call `endRefreshing`.

Comment: or just use `[controller endRefreshing]` as the `handleRefresh:` passes a reference to the `UIRefreshControl`

Comment: Sure. I haven't seen that it's passed to `handleRefresh:`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that UIRefreshControl doesn't require a UITableView at all. `refreshControl` is a [property of UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2127691-refreshcontrol). You can set it on anything that inherits from UIScrollView, which includes UITableView of course, but also other classes such as UICollectionView.