# iOS7 UIRefreshControl changes contentInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UINavigationController` in my app. The `UINavigationBar` is set to opaque and all the scroll views do not overlap underneath the bar.

In one view I have a `UITableView`. The frame of the `UITableView` is `(0 0; 320 504)` on my iPhone 5. i.e. the height is 568 - 64 (the height of the nav bar and status bar).

The `contentInset` of the `UITableView` is `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. When the table view first loads the `contentOffset` is `(0, 0)`.

This is fine. Works brilliantly.

I added a `UIRefreshControl` to the table view. This works a couple of times but then after a few times of doing pull to refresh then the content at the top gets "stuck" under the nav bar.

When this happens I inspect the `contentInset` and it is now `(-60, 0, 0, 0)`.

Is there any way to stop the UIRefreshControl from changing the `contentInset`?

Comment: Removed my answer since you obviuosly already ruled it out. You are calling endRefreshing, I assume?

Comment: No worries. Yeah, when I call `endRefreshing` on the control it disappears. This works fine a few times but then it freaks out and the `contentInset` changes hiding the top few rows under the navigation bar.

Comment: You could probably get away with resetting your frame after the refresh, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I've got round it for now by manually setting the contentInset back to 0 after ending the refresh. But now it doesn't animate the disappearance of the refresh control. It just jumps back. If I try animate it it crashes. lol

Comment: One last thing you might try is adding the UIRefreshControl in IB. on the Storyboard if you click on the UITableviewController, and in the Attributes Inspecter, set the Refreshing setting to enabled, it adds a UIRefresh controll for you. Then you can link an IBAction to it or ad a selector in viewDidLoad. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you might be on to something with that. Unfortunately though, I'm using a UIViewController with a UITableView rather than a UITableViewController. I'll def give it a try next time. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably the reason why `UIRefreshControl` is currently only supported on `UITableViewController`, rather than by addition to any scrollview (which you can get away with, in many cases).

The refresh control does its magic by tinkering with the content insets of the scrollview - particularly when it ends refreshing. Unfortunately the view controller is also tinkering with the content insets of the scroll view to fit it under the translucent nav and status bars. Fun ensues. Is this also an issue on iOS 6 (or, "good old iOS6" as I called it when dealing with the same issue).

The quickest solution is probably to add your table view as a child UITableViewController instead of a simple subview. I think that UITableViewController manages the insets for you at the end of the refresh. If that doesn't work, I've got workarounds for this but it will have to wait until I get back in the office.

Comment: I seem to have fixed this now. I realised that the `completionBlock` of `NSOperation` is called on the same thread as the operation. This is where I was calling `endRefreshing`. I dispatched this to the main thread and it's working now without changing the `contentInset`. Do you have a link to anything about `UIRefreshControl` only officially support `UITVC`?

Comment: The docs say that it is made to be assigned to a UITVC. The addSubview: thing is only mentioned on SO, never in the docs.

Comment: See Dave DeLong's comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12502450/852828

Comment: I changed the whole thing to a uitvc instead and it all works fine now. Even after changing to the main thread I had problems with it showing strange behaviour.

Comment: I am having exactly same problem.I am using UiRefreshControl with a UICollectionView.It seemed to change my contentInset.After endRefresh I am again setting my contentInset to proper value.It that way ok? Or Do we have to refrain from using UIRefreshControl with CollectionView

Answer (score 7):

I will add this answer here in case any one has problems with `UIRefreshControl` by changing the control properties (attributed title, tint, etc...):

Don't mess with the `UIRefreshControl` on `-viewDidLoad:`, use `-viewDidAppear:` instead.

Comment: Make sure that you put a condition if(!refreshControl) else everytime your page appears it add refreshcontrol to it.

Answer (score 5):

Reset your table view contentInset.

```
-(void)pullToRefresh
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need override setContentInset: in you UICollectionView

```
- (void)setContentInset:(UIEdgeInsets)contentInset {
  if (self.tracking) {
    CGFloat difference = contentInset.top - self.contentInset.top;
    CGPoint translation = [self.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self];
    translation.y -= difference * 3.0 / 2.0;
    [self.panGestureRecognizer setTranslation:translation inView:self];
  }
  [super setContentInset:contentInset];
}
```

Comment: URL you mentioned is no more exist