# UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController not calling selector

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, selector, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UIViewController that has a UITableView as a subview. I am trying to add a pull-to-refresh on the table.

Following some examples and discussions that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller/), I have the UIRefresh showing but it never calls the selector. I am not getting notified that the pull action happened.

I cannot use a UITableViewController as my main controller as I need to add a fixed button at the bottom of the screen.

I have the feeling I am missing something out that hopefully is obvious to someone else.

```
@interface ActivityViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end



- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myTableView.delegate = self;

    _myTableView.dataSource = self;

    _tableViewController = [UITableViewController new];

    _tableViewController.tableView = _myTableView;

    [self addChildViewController:_tableViewController]; // Not sure this is necessary

    _refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];

    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    _tableViewController.refreshControl = _refreshControl;

}

- (void)loadMoreData{

    NSLog(@"loadMoreData");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is now working. But I am not sure why!! I kinda left it for a bit, changed other things that needed doing and then tested once more last night and it was working. I admit I am a bit confused. I used the code below from this answer given in earlier posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller/) as I did a few days ago. So thank you for the time and input. It works perfect now, as expected.

```
// Refresh control
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your tableviewcontroller with

```
[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)
```

using `new` does an alloc init but you should use a designated initializer

Comment: That didn't help and actually then I UIRefreshController didn't show at all. The link I added above in my original post has a detailed discussion that explains why it has to be done the way I did it. Just my selector is ignored....

Comment: Ok, I changed that but still my selector - (void)loadMoreData is not called.

Comment: i dont know. maybe try to make your refreshcontroller an instance variable and or check if it is nil at some point and you dont need to     [self addChildViewController:_tableViewController]; // Not sure this is necessary

Comment: Yea I am quite stuck with this problem. Tried many different varieties but can get the selector called. Kinda feel I am missing something silly.