# Weird animation in UIRefreshControl when pulling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I just added a normal UIRefreshControl to my UITableView but it does a weird reframe animation when pulling.

[image]

Anyone knows why can this happen? i'm not modifying the tableView insets or anything.

**EDIT:**
The tableView is a subview in a UIViewController (not a UITableViewController). Added as:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of `UITableViewController`? Or show how you setup the table view in a storyboard?

Comment: Edited the question, not using a UITableViewController ;)

Comment: Well, it's a standard way to setup a refresh control. How do you create your table view, then?

Comment: I do everything in code, nothing strange i think...
 
`self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];`

Answer (score 1):

From the `UIRefreshControl` docs:

> Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a
>   table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a
>   different context can result in undefined behavior.

You can add a "dummy" `UITableViewController` and assign tableView to it (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262249/2128900)).

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

Or alternatively, you can use a custom replacement for the UIRefreshControl - there are many of them on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&o=desc&q=pulltorefresh&ref=cmdform&s=updated&type=Repositories). This way you can also customize the refresh control if you want to.

Comment: I tried with a dummy `UITableViewController` and it does not work (same weird animation).
I also tried with other custom UIRefreshControl, and they do work correctly, but i want to know why the UIRefreshControl is doing that and if there is a way to fix it to use it...

Comment: On the animated GIF I can see that you use kind of a table header (?) - maybe this is the cause? Or maybe try to create UITableView in `loadView` method of `UIViewController` instead of adding it a subview to self.view? I'm just guessing here, I don't know why it doesn't work knowing only the code you posted

Comment: The blue thing is a NavBar