# Migrate UITableView elements for UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I was using a UITableView for developing part of my app and had hence used this following code:

```
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        //[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];

    }];
}
```

However, now I want to use this code in a UIViewController and remove any instances of the tableview entirely. What should I do about the self.tableView areas? How can I make this work?

Sorry if it sounds novice but Im sure its straightforward

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean migrate from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`? If you remove `tableView` you won't have a table.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your `UIViewController` class first, and then in the storyboard drop a `UITableView` onto it, make it by the size of the view (if you want it to be like a `UITableViewController`), and then drag a referencing outlet to the View Controller you've just created (by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and dragging). Then, you can access it through `self.tableView`.

As for your `UIRefreshControl`, I might suggest reading up **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502450/2757380)**, it should help you to migrate completely to a `UIViewController`.
I hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have an instance of UITableView, then please have your `UIViewController` class sub-classed from `UITableViewController`.

A Starter example of it is very well explained here by [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49311/advanced-table-view-animations-tutorial-drop-in-cards)

Just download the starter project & understand the classes.

Hope that helps.