# Using UIRefreshControl with QuickDialog

Tags: objective-c, uirefreshcontrol, quickdialog

How should one use a `UIRefreshControl` with QuickDialog (https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog)? The way I interpret the docs, the control has to be used with a `UITableViewController`, but I don't think QD uses one.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use a `UIRefreshControl` without a `UITableViewController` by just adding it to the `UITableView` as a subview. Alternatively, you can create a `UITableViewController` and just set its tableview as your own, then set the `refreshControl` property.

There is more info and example code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller).