# Pull to Refresh and Parsing data on UIView Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview

i have been reading ur answers i m sure u are pretty experienced so plz help me out .. i m building my first app everything is perfect in it but now i m stuck .. i am not able to pull to refresh nor i am able to add data from parse.com i tried everything but i fail ..

This is how my app looks
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k10svw38se25cno/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Jan%2012%2C%202015%2C%209.56.06%20AM.png?dl=0

i want to pull to refresh when i pull down the screen and i want to parse data for music name and music label n etc etc

nd This is my ViewController.swift
https://www.dropbox.com/s/io76c0shgznswvh/ViewController.rtf?dl=0

i have parse.com framework but i dont know how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

With default look and feel on pull-to-refresh, you could use [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/index.html)

Comment: Where should i add that control n how ?

Comment: found a tutorial, [Implementing Pull-to-Refresh and Handling Empty Table](http://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/). And you might also need [UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Pull to refresh can be implemented using a `UIRefreshControl` but it can only be used in a `UITableViewController`. You are not using a `UITableViewController` in your code.

Comment: You can implement a custom refresh control. Check this project https://github.com/bogardon/MSPullToRefreshController