# UIRefreshControl flicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm experiencing a kind of flicker with my implementation of UIRefreshControl under iOS 8. Every first time I come to the top of my tableView (meaning when the app has just started) I see the flicker shown in the gif below. This does not happen on any subsequent times I come to the top of the tableView until this view is loaded again, so after I did something in another view of the app or restart it altogether.

[image: screen recording of flicker]

This is the code in the viewDidLoad() of my application:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Doing this here to prevent the UIRefreshControl sometimes looking messed up when waking the app
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    updateData()

    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.58, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.43, alpha: 1.0)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "updateData", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

The refreshControl is declared outside of the viewDidLoad() function as I want to call the endRefreshing method from within my updateData() function. This seemed like the obvious way of doing that.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this by changing the following line

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

to

```
tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, atIndex: 0)
```

Thanks to this comment: [UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller?rq=1#comment41734642_12502450)

Comment: even with this, the refreshesControl is shown above the table starting ios 11.x (ios 9 works fine)

Comment: Fixed it for me. This is super bizarre

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of the UIRefreshControl's parent view to be the same as the background color of the UIRefreshControl.

Something like:

`refreshControl.Superview.BackgroundColor = refreshControl.BackgroundColor`