# How do I adjust a UIRefreshControl's position in my view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a custom UIRefreshControl "pull to refresh" and for some reason, when I start to scroll, the view appears above all other views, instead of gradually showing itself as the scroll gets dragged down.. this is what I mean:

[image]

Now I've attempted to patch this up by making the background and tint colors clear in the viewDidLoad:

```
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        collectionView?.addSubview(refreshControl)

    }
```

While this does fix the issue of the refresh just being plastered over everything, regardless of its transparency, the refreshControl is still on top of my view hierarchy, you can see when I release the scroll, the letters are still hanging over the view.. And while it does hide the view, when you begin to drag the scroll, it glitches really fast showing the view again:

[image]

Now I've even tried calling the `sendSubviewToBack` and `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` methods but they don't do anything.. Keep in mind this is a collectionViewController and not a UIViewController with a collectionView on top, so I guess there isn't a view behind the top view which i can send something to the back.. but is there any logic i can implement that will adjust the views bounds when the scrolling begins?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
refreshControl.layer.zPosition = -1
```

Also, be careful about using `UIRefreshControl` without attaching it to an actual `UITableViewController`. You may see odd artifacts like stuttering (even attaching it to just a `UITableView` will cause errors). See:

[UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller)

Comment: when I add it as a subView to my background, it just disappears, i mean the motions of the control are still there but, its not visible

Comment: i can cope with setting the RefreshControl's backgroundColor and tintColor to clear in the viewDidLoad to disguise itself properly, however what can I do about the sudden split second glitch where it negates this code and shows itself when the scroll dragging begins?

Comment: what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: @ItzhakIra do you have sample code, or a video / gif of the problem?

Comment: I think it's best if you add it to your original question, or link to it here (e.g. a public URL using dropbox).

Comment: the zPosition basically does the same as adding it to my backgroundView, it makes it disappear

Comment: Please provide a sample project and share in GitHub.

Comment: heres a link to a video showing the small glitch in the beginning of the scroll dragging https://www.dropbox.com/s/eryzqh0r1l27uv9/GLITCH.mov?dl=0

Comment: as you can see, the code I added to make it clear when the view loads works, however for a small split second when the dragging begins, it shows itself