# iOS - UITableView's UIRefreshControl vs. UITableViewController's UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

In my `UIViewController`, I have a `UITableView` as one of the subviews. I add my `UIRefreshControl` with the following code:

```
// enable "pull to refresh"
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh!" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(fetchArticles) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

I have another screen in my app that uses a `UITableViewController`, and its `UIRefreshControl` is way more different than the one I added for my `UITableView`.

The `UIRefreshControl` for a separate `UITableView` is slower when dragging and I usually have to drag FARTHER just to get it to start refreshing.

The `UIRefreshControl` for my `UITableViewController` on my other screen is faster when dragging and I don't have to drag so far to get it to start refreshing.

I prefer the smoother behavior of the `UITableViewController`'s `UIRefreshControl`, so how do I get my `UIRefreshControl`for my `UITableView` to behave more like the default one that belongs to `UITableViewController`?

Is this possible? Or is using a `UIContainerView` and using `UITableViewController` my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIRefreshControl` is designed to work with a `UITableViewController`; on Apple's website it says:

> Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.

That being said, people have been successful without a `UITableViewController`: [UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller). Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was a little hesitant to use the hacky `UITableViewController` instance solution but it worked perfectly!