# UITableView and UIRefreshControl doesn't showen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableView i try to add a UIRefreshControl but it's never showen i tried several things

For example :

```
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:    #selector(EvenementsViewController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents:    UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    uitableViewAlert!.addSubview(refreshControl) // not required when using UITableViewController
    uitableViewAlert!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

but can't see the UIRefreshControl

any help will be appreciated

-------------------Edit --------------------

I finally just find the solution

in xib file, uitableview in scrollview part i check bounces and bounce vertically and now it works. thanks guys for your help

Comment: have you try the UIScrollView+DXRefresh class?

Comment: no, i will look at it right now

Comment: you have viewController and in that you have taken tableView right?

Comment: yes i have class AlertesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @SaurabhJain with dxrefresh i have the same problem :(

Comment: You don't have to manually add `UIRefreshControl` into view hierarchy. Instead assign `tableView.refreshControl` property and controller will take care of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C :

you can set refresh controller as follow for `tableView` inside `ViewController`:

```
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [uitableViewAlert addSubview:refreshControl];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//Action : 

-(IBAction)refreshTable:(id)sender
{
   //do the refresh task
}
```

**OR**

Better way to instantiate a `UITableViewController`, and then setting your `UIRefreshControl` and `UITableView` to that, i.e.:

```
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    tableViewController.tableView = uitableViewAlert;

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [tableViewController setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
```

Comment: the first solution is the same thing that i do in swift, the second one i dont undestand how UITableViewController will be showen i already try it but nothing change

Comment: my problem was bounce and bounce vertically i checked that and now it works. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hope can help you

```
 var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
 refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData),
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
 refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "下拉刷新数据")
 self.tableView?.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Comment: my problem was bounce and bounce vertically i checked that and now it works. thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-) please look at [answer]

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

For Refresh view we need to do only this thing in our code:-

```
 let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

//MARK:- Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NotificationVC.getlistPromotion), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
 refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
 refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refresh...")
 tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

internal func getlistPromotion(){
//Do something here for Refresh table data
}

//and Finally for stop need to do
 self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Answer (score 0):

UIRefreshControl works 100% properly with instance of UITableViewController only. You can track similar issue here: [UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller)

Comment: my problem was bounce and bounce vertically i checked that and now it works. thanks for your help