# Pull to refresh on Tableview which has multiple sections but every section contains only one row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a tableview which has multiple sections and headers but every section has one row in which there is a collection view. I want to implement pull to refresh method on this tableview. Adding refresh control is working on other tableviews in application.

I have tried bellow code

```
refreshCustomers= [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]; 
[refreshCustomers addTarget:self action:@selector(customersRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.customer addSubview:refreshCustomers];
```

Comment: What is your  issue can you please specify?

Comment: Refresh control is not working for Tableview which has sections, while in other tableviews which has rows its working fine

Comment: You have tableview controller or viewcontroller ?

Comment: I am using view controller

Comment: Refer this link that may help you  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Its working with other tableviews which have multiple row but one of the tableview which has multiple sections its not working

Comment: Then show some code, what you have tried?

Comment: refreshCustomers= [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshCustomers addTarget:self action:@selector(customersRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.customer addSubview:refreshCustomers];

Comment: self.customer is my tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.customer;

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(customersRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```