# Parse: loadObjects/refreshing the tableview after a pull to refresh

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pull-to-refresh

***Swift***

I'm trying to make it so when you pull to refresh on the tableview it updates the tableview with the data that is stored on Parse.com

I've researched this and it seems I need to use `loadObjects()`

When I place this in it says: "Use of unresolved identifier 'loadObjects'

Not sure if this is what I need or not..

Here is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import ParseUI

class EventsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var timer: NSTimer!
var isAnimating = false
var currentColorIndex = 0
var currentLabelIndex = 0
var customView: UIView!
var labelsArray: Array<UILabel> = []
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
var testArray = [String]()
var subArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)

    loadCustomRefreshContents()

    //refreshControl colors
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //color of background
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor() //color of indicator

    let query = PFQuery(className: "events")
    let runkey = query.orderByDescending("eventTitle")
    runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {

                    let load = object.objectForKey("eventTitle") as! String
                    self.testArray.append(load)

                    let subload = object.objectForKey("date") as! String
                    self.subArray.append(subload)

                    print(self.testArray)
                }

            }
        } else {

            print("error:\(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }

    }
    sleep(3)
    do_table_refresh()

    loadViewIfNeeded()

    loadObjects()

    /*let url = NSURL(string: "https://m.facebook.com/CathedralCityMunicipal")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            print(urlContent)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent! as String, baseURL: nil)

            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()*/

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func do_table_refresh() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        self.tableview.reloadData()
        return

    }

}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return testArray.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = self.testArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.subTitle.text = self.subArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//refreshes tableview; starts refresh
func loadCustomRefreshContents() {
    let refreshContents = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RefreshControl", owner: self, options: nil)

    customView = refreshContents[0] as! UIView
    customView.frame = refreshControl.bounds

    for var i=0; i<customView.subviews.count; ++i {
        labelsArray.append(customView.viewWithTag(i + 1) as! UILabel)
    }

    refreshControl.addSubview(customView)

    do_table_refresh()

}

//stops refresh
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    do_table_refresh()

    if refreshControl.refreshing {
        if !isAnimating {
            doSomething()
            animateRefreshStep1()
            self.do_table_refresh()
        }
    }
}

//cycles through colors
func getNextColor() -> UIColor {
    var colorsArray: Array<UIColor> = [UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.brownColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

    if currentColorIndex == colorsArray.count {
        currentColorIndex = 0
    }

    let returnColor = colorsArray[currentColorIndex]
    ++currentColorIndex

    return returnColor
}

func doSomething() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "endOfWork", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.do_table_refresh()

}

func endOfWork() {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    self.do_table_refresh()
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

//first part of animation
func animateRefreshStep1() {
    isAnimating = true

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
        self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].textColor = self.getNextColor()

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[self.currentLabelIndex].textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    ++self.currentLabelIndex

                    if self.currentLabelIndex < self.labelsArray.count {
                        self.animateRefreshStep1()
                    }
                    else {
                        self.animateRefreshStep2()
                    }
            })
    })
}

//second part of animation
func animateRefreshStep2() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.labelsArray[0].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[1].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[2].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[3].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[4].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[5].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[6].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[8].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
        self.labelsArray[9].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.labelsArray[0].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[1].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[2].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[3].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[4].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[5].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[6].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[7].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[8].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.labelsArray[9].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    if self.refreshControl.refreshing {
                        self.currentLabelIndex = 0
                        self.animateRefreshStep1()
                    }
                    else {
                        self.isAnimating = false
                        self.currentLabelIndex = 0
                        for var i=0; i<self.labelsArray.count; ++i {
                            self.labelsArray[i].textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                            self.labelsArray[i].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                        }
                    }
            })
    })
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

I have tried letting the `do_table_refresh()` function run after the refresh is over, but the tableview does not update. I have also tried using `self.tableview.reloadData()` but also does not work.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

Feel free to ask me for any additional information!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: maybe this is what youre missing: #import <Bolts/Bolts.h>

Comment: @ivan gives me errors when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you are trying to get the Parse data everytime you to pull-to-refresh you should query for them always.

Keep your query into a single function and call a tableView.reloadData() so it will reload the tableView every time you query your events:

```
func loadEvents () -> Void {

        self.testArray = []
        self.subArray = []

        let query = PFQuery(className: "events")
        let runkey = query.orderByDescending("eventTitle")
        runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {


                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    for object in objects {

                        let load = object.objectForKey("eventTitle") as! String
                        self.testArray.append(load)

                        let subload = object.objectForKey("date") as! String
                        self.subArray.append(subload)

                        //reload TableView
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        print(self.testArray)
                    }

                }
            } else {

                print("error:\(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }

        }

        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

And then add a Target for your UIRefreshControl inside your `ViewDidLoad()`

```
 refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("loadEvents"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
 self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Also, you must declare your UIRefreshControl as follows:

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

Comment: I added the function and the other bit of code to my viewDidLoad() But when I ran it it gave me: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on the refreshControl.addTarget line.

Comment: @Hunter did you add `addTarget` after you instantiated `refreshControl`?

also, you might want to do a lazy load on the `refreshControl`:           

`lazy var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`

Comment: @FabianBuentello did I add what?

Comment: @FabianBuentello I did have `addTarget` before I instantiated `refreshControl` and I moved it down after it which caused the error to become fixed and for it to pull data from Parse. But now every time I pull to refresh it, it make duplicate cells. For example if the cells were: one, two, three, the table would become: one, two, three, one two, three, after the refresh.

Comment: To see a more concise form of @adolfosrs answer, just reference -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15010646/1973339

Comment: @Hunter, you have 2 options at this point, either clear out the array which holds the information, or simply check if any objects have been added. I like to use the [Dollar Framework](https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift#union---union) for this. Specifically the `union` method. Check it out if you haven't used it before.

Comment: @adolfosrs I used the clear arrays method and it works for not getting duplicates. Thank you for your help! Merry Christmas!

Comment: @FabianBuentello Thank you for your time and help! Merry Christmas!

Comment: Merry Christmas guys. :)