# Is there anyway to create a UITableView with one universal footer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to create a `UITableView` with multiple sections. Each section has it's own header, but I am trying to make a universal footer for the entire table view that stays in one position...

Is this logic possible using the `UITableViewDelegate` methods? Or should I create a custom view and just try and add it as a subview to my table view? The footer I currently have contains a `UIButton`.

If anyone has some sample code that would be great.

Edit: This question is not the same as the one referenced. I am trying to make a universal footer that floats above the `UITableView`. The other question does not specify the location of the footer, only that a footer is desired.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Simply implement `tableView:titleForFooterInSection` and ignore the `section` parameter.

Comment: Matthias that would put a footer after every section.

Comment: @NathanWhite - Right now I have the view added using  `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: I have solved my problem and would be happy to share the code but the question has been marked a duplicate.

Comment: You can still edit your question though can't you? That way you can include your solution in the question itself.

Comment: @hugh -  Yeah I edited the question and they un-marked it as a duplicate. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a subview and adding my button to that view. I then made that view my "footer".

Here is the code that gave me the desired results.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

//self.tableView.delegate = self;
//self.tableView.dataSource = self;

//save current tableview, then replace view with a regular uiview
self.tableView = (UITableView*)self.view;
UIView *replacementView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
self.view = replacementView;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

UIView *footerView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 370, 320, 45)];

//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

//the button should be as big as a table view cell
//width of the button can be set but the width of the view it is added to will always match the width of the tableView
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 200, 45)]; 

//set title, font size and font color
[button setTitle:@"Build" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];   
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set action of the button
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buildThenSegue)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//add the button to the view
[footerView addSubview:button];
footerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:footerView];
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

}

Take note that this is in a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

I referenced this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084267/1091868

Answer (score 4):

read about UITableView's tableFooterView property.

And now some code: (using ARC)

```
UILabel *footer = [UILabel alloc] init];
footer.text = @"Some text" ;
footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer;
```

Now at the bottom of entire tableview there is a UILabel that is green with some text.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for... I tried this out and it added a footer at the very bottom of the table view. I would like the footer to stay "floating" in the same positon (right above the `UITabBarController` selections.

My table view will most likely have 3-4 sections with 5-10 rows in each section so I don't want the user to have to scroll through all that crap when they need to tap the `UIButton` to segue to the next view.

Comment: I know no way to do that with the method I gave you.  I think you will have to layout something in code or IB.  Full Screen View that contains a tableview and a UIView locked to the bottom of the FullScreeView. Then the table would be set to hold the rest of the area.