# how to do one constant (no scrolling) section in table Xcode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

how to do one constant (no scrolling) section in table

+---------+
|***_*__*_*__**|
|***_*__*_*__**|
|***_*__*_*__**|
|***_*__*_*__**|
|***_*__*_*__**|
|***_*__*_*__**|

and last section has to constant. How to do?
When i scroll my table i want by last section was all the time on screen.

Comment: Please explain your problem.

Comment: y don't u add a UIView over the table view and show the data there by adding labels to it so that it looks constant

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed header to UITableview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951190/fixed-header-to-uitableview)

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084177/is-there-anyway-to-create-a-uitableview-with-one-universal-footer?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Better to have two different TableViews. Place the dynamic data source table at the top of the view and Constant section's table at the bottom of the view.