# How to scroll the header along with the UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a header. the problem I currently have is that the header doesn't scroll with the table. I need it to scroll off screen (above) when the user scrolls the table view up. the tableview scrolls but the header is locked at the top of the `UIView`.

thanks

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // add user profile image to _contentView
    UIImageView *userImageView;

    UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userProfileImageUrl]]];

    userImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:userImage];
    userImageView.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,90,100);

   [sectionHeader addSubview:userImageView];

   // return userImageView;

    // user name lable
    CGRect userNameFrame = CGRectMake(110, 60, 100, 50 );
    UILabel* userNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: userNameFrame];
    [userNameLabel setText: firstName];
    [userNameLabel setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    [userNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [userNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:14]];

    [sectionHeader addSubview:userNameLabel];

    // user last name label
    CGRect userLastNameFrame = CGRectMake(110, 75, 100, 50 );
    UILabel* userLastNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: userLastNameFrame];
    [userLastNameLabel setText: lastName];
    [userLastNameLabel setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    [userLastNameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [userLastNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:14]];

    [sectionHeader addSubview:userLastNameLabel];

    // user checkin view
    UIView *userCheckinView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 280, 25)];
    userCheckinView.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    [sectionHeader addSubview:userCheckinView];

    // check in label
    UILabel* userCheckInLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 2, 100, 20)];
    [userCheckInLabel setText: @"CHECK-IN"];
    userCheckInLabel.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    userCheckInLabel.textColor = customColorIt;
    [userCheckInLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:12]];

    [userCheckinView addSubview:userCheckInLabel];

    // image
    UIImageView *checkinImg = [[UIImageView alloc]
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"classifica_geotag_C.png"]];
    checkinImg.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 24, 24);
    [userCheckinView addSubview:checkinImg];

    // check in label
    UILabel* userCheckInCountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 2, 20, 20)];
    [userCheckInCountLabel setText: [checkinCount stringValue]];
    userCheckInCountLabel.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    userCheckInCountLabel.textColor = customColorIt;
    [userCheckInCountLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:12]];

    [userCheckinView addSubview:userCheckInCountLabel];

    // user like view
    UIView *userLikeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 150, 280, 25)];
    userLikeView.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    [sectionHeader addSubview:userLikeView];

    // like label
    UILabel* userLikeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 2, 100, 20)];
    [userLikeLabel setText: @"LIKE"];
    userLikeLabel.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    userLikeLabel.textColor = customColorIt;
    [userLikeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:12]];

    [userLikeView addSubview:userLikeLabel];

    // image
    UIImageView *likeImg = [[UIImageView alloc]
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"classifica_like_C.png"]];
    likeImg.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 24, 24);
    [userLikeView addSubview:likeImg];

    // user like label
    UILabel* userLikeCountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 2, 20, 20)];
    [userLikeCountLabel setText: [likesCount stringValue]];
    userLikeCountLabel.backgroundColor = customColorGrey;
    userLikeCountLabel.textColor = customColorIt;
    [userLikeCountLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Regular" size:12]];

    [userLikeView addSubview:userLikeCountLabel];


    // la mia bacheca like view
    userLaMiaView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 180, 300, 25)];
    userLaMiaView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [sectionHeader addSubview:userLaMiaView];


    // like label
    UILabel* userLaMiaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 150, 20)];
    [userLaMiaLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"LA MIA BACHECA", nil)];

    userLaMiaLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    userLaMiaLabel.textColor = customColorGrey;
    [userLaMiaLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Bold" size:10]];

    [userLaMiaView addSubview:userLaMiaLabel];

    // grey line view below la mia label
    userGreyLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 248, 280, 1.5)];
    userGreyLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [sectionHeader addSubview:userGreyLineView];


    return sectionHeader;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 210;
}
```

Comment: changing `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` worked for me

Answer (score 45, accepted):

create sectionHeader view in a new method and then add to the end:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader;
```

Comment: changing `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` worked for me

Comment: changing `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` might work but I dont think is the right approach, looks more like a patch. If in the future you have multiple sections and diff headers, that will break.

Answer (score 74):

That behavior is only common when the `UITableViewStyle` property of the table is set to `UITableViewStylePlain`. If you have it set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, the headers will scroll up with the cells.

This answer is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers).

This solution works regardless of the number of headers.

Comment: `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; // Get headers to scroll`

Answer (score 22):

if you have dynamic header view  or single view select table style [image: select table view style as <code>group</code> table]

Answer (score 12):

Changing the `UITableViewStyle` from `Plain` to `Grouped` make the section header to scroll with the other cells.

Answer (score 6):

If you write `tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader` you will lose the actual table view header.
If you want to have table view header along with section headers you have to set `UITableViewStyle` property to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.
Also if you want to calculate section header height automatically you can `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `heightForHeaderInSection` method like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a single header in the table then you can use  `tableHeaderView` as below:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = Header;
```

Or if you have multiple header in table than you need to use Group table instead of plain table.

Thanks