# Continuous scrolling between tableView and scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, xlpagertabstrip

I have a parent scroll view with a uiview header and table view. I am trying to have a similar behavior to Twitter or Instagram profile page. You start scrolling the parent scroll view and as soon as the header is gone there is a **continuous** transition from the scroll view scrolling to the table view scrolling without having to lift my finger and replace it on the table view. Right now the current behavior is a little jank. I have to lift my finger and put it on the table view after the scroll view content offset is past the header to start swiping the table view.

MainViewController

```
    import UIKit
    import XLPagerTabStrip

    class MainViewController: UIViewController {

        lazy var headerViewController: UIViewController = {
            let header = UIViewController()
            return header
        }()

        lazy var bottomViewControllers: BottomPageViewController = {
            let bvc = BottomPageViewController()
            return bvc
        }()

        lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
            let sv = UIScrollView()
            sv.delegate = self
            sv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            sv.bounces = true
            sv.bounces = false
            return sv
        }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        let f = UIScreen.main.bounds
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: f.minX, y: f.minY, width: f.width, height: f.height)

        add(headerViewController, to: scrollView, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: f.width, height: 150))
        add(bottomViewControllers, to: scrollView, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: headerViewController.view.bounds.height, width: f.width, height: f.height))
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: f.width, height: f.height * 2)

        if let vcs = bottomViewControllers.viewControllers as? [BottomViewController] {
            for vc in vcs {
                vc.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }

}

extension MainViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let controllers = bottomViewControllers.viewControllers as? [BottomViewController] else { return }
        let selectedController = controllers[bottomViewControllers.currentIndex]
        if self.scrollView == scrollView {
            selectedController.tableView.isScrollEnabled = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 150
            print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = !selectedController.tableView.isScrollEnabled
            bottomViewControllers.view.frame.origin.y = max(150, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }


    }
}

extension MainViewController: CustomScrollDelegate {
    func tableViewScroll(_ viewController: BottomViewController) {
        print(viewController.tableView.contentOffset.y)
        viewController.tableView.isScrollEnabled = viewController.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0
    }
}
```

BottomViewController

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

protocol CustomScrollDelegate {
    func tableViewScroll(_ viewController: BottomViewController)
}

class BottomViewController: UITableViewController {

    var pageTitle: String?
    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var delegate: CustomScrollDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.tableView.bounces = true
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TETST")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TETST", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1000
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        delegate?.tableViewScroll(self)
    }

    init(pageTitle: String, pageIndex: Int) {
        self.pageTitle = pageTitle
        self.pageIndex = pageIndex
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension BottomViewController: IndicatorInfoProvider {
    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return IndicatorInfo.init(title: pageTitle ?? "Tab \(pageIndex)")
    }
}
```

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add your header as a header to the `UITableView` (not a section header!) and let it scroll with the rest of the `UITableView`: [How to scroll the header along with the UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635056/how-to-scroll-the-header-along-with-the-uitableview/32078157)

Also you can make the `UITableView` link it's  `contentSize` directly to it's height so the `UITableView` itself doesn't scroll at all, ever, like this: [Resizing UITableView to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content)

It all kind of depends if you add rows dynamically by paging etcetera how complex your solution would be. But I think you would get there most of the time by simply setting up the `UITableView` header in the correct mode

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 table views side by side so I need a separate view for a global header

Comment: Take a `UIScrollView`, add an inner `UIView`, add the header at the top and both `UITableView`s below it. Then monitor the `contentSize` of _both_ tableviews and set that as the _minimum_ height of that `UITableView` as a constraint. Now the tallest `UITableView` will always push out the inner `UIView` to the correct height and the shortest `UITableView` will simply get longer without any layout error. Let me know if this works and I'll update the answer.