# how can i make headerView scroll (not stay on the top of the tableview ) accompanying with UItableViewCell when i was scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

in plainsytle tableview , we set headerViews for each section by delegate method

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

so,when i scrolling up tableview , the first section's headerView is always showing on the top of tableview before the section totally disappear on the tableview , then the second section's headerView will show on the top of tableview instead . so my question is how can i make headerView scroll accompanying with uitableViewCell , just like group style tableview ?

Comment: You can by creating tableview with UITableViewStyleGrouped style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

subclass the UITableView and override this method

```
- (BOOL)allowsHeaderViewsToFloat{
    return NO;
}
```

same for footer

```
- (BOOL)allowsFooterViewToFloat{
    return NO;
}
```

But I think that this is a private API ... You will not be able to submit it to the AppStore

If you will upload it to the AppStore; Then you have two other options

1. Adding a normal cell instead of the section header
2. If you have only one section, then you can simply use table header instead of section header

Comment: I put it in a category instead of subclassing, and it passed the review \m/.

Answer (score 28):

You can disable scrolling sectionHeader by changing the table property to -

```
UITableViewStyleGrouped
```

You have to set it on the initialisation of UITableView.

- Change Table Style from `Plain` to `Grouped` on StoryBoard

OR

```
UITableView* table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 21):

Just change style of table from "Plain" to "Grouped".

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and when i browsed i came to this link [See The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers)   from and I came to conclusion that you need to set tableViewHeader Style to Group and it works Charm.

Comment: Nice and simple, no subclassing needed :D

Answer (score 6):

You can change the style of the tableView.

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you ve more than one section, you can customize it using some thirdt party API

else you can try this using Grouped table instead of plain tableView.

Try like this when you assign custom view as tableView Header view it becomes header view for table and it will scroll with the table view

```
 -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        UIView *sectionView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];

        tableView.tableHeaderView =sectionView;

        return sectionView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `UITableViewStyle` of the table from `UITableViewStylePlain` to  `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, this will make the header scroll up with cells.

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

As Hani Ibrahim pointed out you need to subclass UITableView. Apple says you :
`must specify style at creation.`

So:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: .grouped)
```

Notice how my super.init uses .grouped as the style.
For this style of tableview (.grouped) Apple also says:

```
Summary

A table view whose sections present distinct groups of rows. The section headers and footers do not float.
```

Then you can call the following tableView delegate methods:
`viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` 
(notice those are for headers only, use the footer counterparts if you want footers too)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerLabel = UILabel()
        headerLabel.text = "My cool header title"
        headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 16)
        return headerLabel
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
```

And that should do it! Good luck.

Comment: Or just let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)

Answer (score 0):

Disable scrolling section header by changing the property from Storyboard

Storyboard

1. Attributes inspector
2. Style
3. Change Style from plain to Grouped from the dropdown

[image]