# UiView on top of the TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to put a UIView (banner) on top of the list (tableView), so the UIview will not disappear when the user scrolls down the list. 
I tried this code, but didn't work.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.view.addSubview(banner)
    banner.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
}
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var rect = self.banner.frame
    rect.origin.y = max(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top)
    self.banner.frame = rect
}
```

Any advice how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Please share your design, what you exact want to do

Comment: why are you using scroll view function with a table view? you only defined the width of the banner, what about height?

Comment: Are you subclassing your view controller from `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`? Can you share a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @f_qi I added height, but no change.

Comment: @lukas28277 please take a look at the answer by Kyle, I think his approach could solve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView with fixed section headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to keep the view within the `scrollView`, a much easier method would be to use a standard `UIViewController` with a `UIView` attached to the top using `AutoLayout` with `constraints` and `UITableView` attached to the bottom of the `UIView` and the bottom of the `UIViewController`.

With this layout, only your smaller `tableView` would be scrolling and your `UIView` would be stationary in place, outside the scope of the scrolling `UITableViewCells`.

If you are currently using an `UITableViewController`, you'll need to remove the `override` modifiers from your `tableView` methods, make your `UIViewController` implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, then attach the `delegates` either in code or storyboard.

Your new `UIViewController` would look like this at the top:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I thought there should be a way, how to stick the uiview to the top , because it is not the part of the main cells of the list (tableView)

Comment: @lukas28277 there is. check the duplicate link I just made.

Comment: @lukas28277 the fact that the view is not part of the main cells of the list is the exact reason i would recommend my approach. it completely separates this accessory view you are describing from your tableview and the tableview's logic.