# How to add a view on top of UITableView that scrolls together, but stick to top after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView with height of 100 pixels that's on top of my UITableView. When I scroll up I want the UIView to scroll together with my UITableView as if it's part it. When 50 pixels of my UIView is hidden from scrolling up, I want to pin the UIView at the top while I continue scrolling up. How can this be achieved? I tried using changing my UIView's top NSLayoutConstraint constant equal to my tableview's content offset, but they don't scroll at the same speed.

Comment: You should take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17583567/6203030 what you are looking for is the style of the tableView

Answer (score 5):

First make sure your tableView is `grouped`:

```
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY)!, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: (self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY)!)), style: .grouped)
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

Then you need to add the `UIView` into the `subview` of your `tableView`:

```
self.myView = UIView()
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
self.tableView.addSubview(self.myView)
```

Add a header of height 100 for your tableView's first section so that your cells are at right place:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Then adjust the frame of your `UIView` when scrolling:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if(offset > 50){
        self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offset - 50, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
    }else{
        self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic way to do this and the best answer I have found for it. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you'r question correctly, You can do it by implementing table view `scrollViewDidScroll:` method  like this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static CGFloat previousOffset;
    CGRect rect = self.yourUIView.frame;

   //NSLog you'r UIView position before putting any condition 
   // NSLog(@"Origin %f",rect.origin.y);

    rect.origin.y += previousOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    previousOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    //assuming you'r UIView y position starts from 0
    //Before setting the condition please make sure to run without any 
    //condition if not working

    if(rect.origin.y>=-50 && rect.origin.y<=0){
            self.yourUIView.frame = rect;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement the `viewForHeader inSection` method for your tableView (remember to make your ViewController implementing the tableviewDelegate protocol) and once you've got it you should set your tableViewStyle to `UITableViewStylePlain`

Share your code if you are interested in more help.

Source: [UITableView with fixed section headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and

`tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

For me nothing from any above options can help but I realised that you can just call

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top), animated: false)
```

in `viewDidload()` and problem gone! :)

Totally forgot about this method and spent too much time for this creepy behavior.

Good Luck!