# How to prevent tableview section head from sticking while scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with many sections. I am using an actual tableview cell which I dequeue to use as a custom section header. The issue I am having is when I scroll the section header "sticks" to the top of the table until the next section appears.

How can I prevent this from happening and actually have it scroll up like normal?

Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    return UIView()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView with fixed section headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers)

Comment: It kinda helps out but I do not want my tableview to be grouped since it makes it look different( kinda like the settings app).

Answer (score 24):

Do following steps.

**From @IB**

1. Select your tableView
2. Go to Attribute Inspector
3. Find Style Attribute drop down which is `Plain` by default
4. Change it to `Grouped`

Or if you are creating TableView **Programmatically** use

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: YourFrame, style: .Grouped)
```

Comment: @MassimoPavanel I believe that one day you will do the same for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Change UITableViewStyle to UITableViewStyleGrouped.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions :

1. If you have just one section then set the Tableview Header property to the UIView you want to set as the Section Header.
2. If you have multiple sections, change the row count for each section to (number of rows for that section + 1) and make the row at 0th index to be a header. Some hand coding will be required.
3. Change your tableview to grouped, will require UI redesign so that the design looks similar to a plain tableview cell.

Answer (score 2):

Set `UITableViewStyle` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, the headers will scroll up with the cells.
and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 0.000001;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Go to `Mainstoryboard`

Step2: Click on Your `Tableview`

Step3: Go to `Attribute Inspector`

Step4: Find `Style Attribute` drop down which is `Plain` by default

Step5: Change it to `Grouped`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UIHeaderViewCell`, You should use a `UITableViewCell`. Make section header height as 0 and for every 0th item in that section , display a `UITableViewCell` with heading on it