# Changing the title of the table when an spesefic that changes in table in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a table view which I populate it with the data that I receive from the database. There is an element in my table which is the Date that data added to the database and I'm showing it. All the data are sorted in order of the date in the database, therefore there is no problem with sorting them is my app. When the user is scrolling down the table he is seeing the date but I need to make that date to be set as a header to the top of the table view and when the user passes that data the date get changed in the header.
I found nothing related in StackOverflow, But I found a tutorial in [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePCliV2CsuU) but it had a problem which was just for collection view and I'm not the good one that I was looking for. could anybody give me a clue or a similar code to understand the logic and requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix header at top of the table view you have to use [UITableViewStylePlain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/plain) style for it.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers?noredirect=1&lq=1).